# Graphql tools - mergeTypeDefs sort alphabetically

Tags: graphql, graphql-tools

I'm using the following code to merge 2 typesDefs to one:

```
import { mergeTypeDefs } from '@graphql-tools/merge';
import topicsTypes from '../modules/topics/typeDefs';
import contentTypes from '../modules/content/typeDefs';

const types = [contentTypes, topicsTypes];

export default mergeTypeDefs(types)
```

When I run `graphql-schema-linter` I get an error:

`22:1 The fields of object type` Query `should be sorted in alphabetical order. Expected sorting: contentAccessTokenByUUID, documentContent, documentTopics type-fields-sorted-alphabetically`

I tried changing the order of the types in the array to `[topicsTypes, contentTypes];`

But I get the same error, how can I force `mergeTypeDefs` to merge the defs alphabetically?

Answer (score 0):

Try to import your schemas as shown below
Depending on your file extension edit the following

```js
     import { mergeTypeDefs } from '@graphql-tools/merge';
     import { loadFilesSync } from '@graphql-tools/load-files';
        
     const typesArray = loadFilesSync('./schema', {
              extensions: ['gql'],
            });
     const typeDefs = mergeTypeDefs(typesArray, { throwOnConflict: true, sort: true });

     export default typeDefs;
```

If you want to check out the doc
New mergeTypeDefs-routine from https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/migration-from-merge-graphql-schemas/

Also might be helpful to check out this https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/api/interfaces/merge_src.Config#throwonconflict